# Undefined references appears when including iostream

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have tried to compile very simple code for android:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo()
{
}
```

But I get some linking errors:

```
/home/l/android-ndk-r7b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/iostream:72: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
/home/l/eclipse_workspace/android_bt_test1/jni/native.cpp:33: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
```

My Application.mk is:

```
APP_OPTIM := debug
APP_MODULES := native_lab
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

My Android.mk is:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := native_lab
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -ldl -lstdc++ -llog
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include /home/l/android-ndk-r7b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/ /home/l/android-ndk-r7b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/include
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I know this problem is very easy, but I have't found a resolution.
Could anybody help me please?

Comment: Are you sure you link against the correct libstdc++ ? I recall having a similar problem once with the NDK, and I solved it by double-checking my LD paths.